# PHP - Detecting remote host disconnection

Tags: php, sockets

According to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php), `socket_read()` is supposed to return `FALSE` when the remote host has closed the connection, and an empty string `''` when there is no more data to read.  However, during my testing, it never returns `FALSE`, even when I close the remote host connection.  Here is the relevant code:

```
$data = '';

do {
    $read = socket_read($socket, 1024);

    if ($read === FALSE) {
        throw new SocketDisconnectException();
    }

    $data .= $read;
} while ($read !== '');
```

The `SocketDisconnectException` never gets thrown, even when I disconnect the remote host connection.  I've double and triple checked that I'm not catching the exception and discarding it, and even thrown in an `echo` and `exit` into the conditional as a sanity check.

Has the behavior of this function changed, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug where if you're using PHP_NORMAL_READ it will return false on remote disconnect, but PHP_BINARY_READ will return "".  PHP_BINARY_READ is the default, I'd suggest trying PHP_NORMAL_READ if that works for your purposes.